# Wraping a link to a table cell with the result of a jQuery AJAX $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table with a calendar and I want to set a link, to some days, that I get from a jQuery AJAX $.get. But, I'm getting all links nested in the same cell.

I collect the elements that will get the link:

```
var bookings = document.getElementsByClassName('table-danger');
```

With this loop, first I pick up the id from each element inside `bookings`, which I use to get the `idbooking` from the data base with a $.get. The results are correct, the problem comes when I try to set the links:

```
for(var i = 0; i < bookings.length; i++){

   var booking = bookings[i].getAttribute('id');

   $.get("/admin/bookings/getidbooking", {
   date: booking
   },

   function(idbooking){
      console.log(idbooking);
      $("#" + booking).wrap($('<a>').attr('href', '/admin/bookings/booking?idbooking=' + idbooking));
   });
}
```

As a result, I get all links nested in the same cell:

```
<tr> 
    <td class="invisible" id="2017-07-31">31</td> 
    <td class="table-success" id="2017-08-01">1</td> 
    <td class="table-success" id="2017-08-02">2</td> 
    <td class="table-success" id="2017-08-03">3</td> 
    <td class="table-danger" id="2017-08-04">4</td> 
    <td class="table-danger" id="2017-08-05">5</td> 
    <a href="/admin/bookings/booking?idbooking=18">
      <a href="/admin/bookings/booking?idbooking=18">
        <a href="/admin/bookings/booking?idbooking=18">
          <td class="table-danger" id="2017-08-06">6</td>
        </a>
       </a>
     </a>
</tr>
```

Those links should have been set at the id's: 2017-08-04, 2017-08-05 and 2017-08-06, but they are all nested in the last one.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the values to be treated in an array, and handling them over a for loop, has provided to be a wrong approach. **The solution was to set a jQuery click() event to those values**.

This is the extract of the code that has worked out:

```
$("td.table-danger").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
 }).click(function(){
    var idDate = this.id;
    $(this).css('cursor', 'progress');

    $.get("/admin/bookings/getidbooking", {
        date: idDate
        },
        function(idbooking){
            $('.modal-body').load(url + idbooking, 
            function(){
                $("#bookingDetails").modal({show:true});
            });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have ID attribute saved in `booking`, so you don't need to use `document.getElementById`.

You need to replace

```
   $(document.getElementById(booking)).wrap($('<a>').attr('href', '/admin/bookings/booking?idbooking=' + idbooking));
```

with

```
   $("#" + booking).wrap($('<a>').attr('href', '/admin/bookings/booking?idbooking=' + idbooking));
```

Below is simple demo:

```js
var booking = 'someId';
var idbooking = 1;
$("#" + booking).wrap($('<a>').attr('href', '/admin/bookings/booking?idbooking=' + idbooking));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someId">Example</div>
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it behaves in the same way. My problem is that all links, are nested on the same cell. Thanks any way @Milan Chheda

Comment: That's not a valid HTML. You cannot have `<a>` inside an `<a>`

Comment: That's what I want to avoid, but for some reason, the loop wraps all links on the same element.

Comment: So are you saying, that the TD already has an `<a>` tag and we are adding more? If TD already has an `<a>`, we should rather update the `href` of that `<a>` tag, right?

Comment: No, all <a> tags are generated by the for loop, but instead of being set at the right element, they are all nested at the last one.

Comment: I believe, its because of the AJAX behaviour. In that case, you should not use `booking` variable. Rather, send the booking value also in the response and you it from response.